# Excel if statement comparing string values

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I want to use the if formula to return value if the various conditions are met, eg. I have a supplier code, and item description and a rate, the Rate field is populated using vlookup from another table with only Supplier_code and Rate.
I then want to use a formula to only return a Rate, in the Actual_Rate's column with the item description doesn't continue a value.

```
Supplier_code    Item Description     Rate
1234             Pen Red              5.00  
1234             Pen Blue             5.00 
1234             Pen Black            5.00
1234             Book Black           5.00
1234             Book Blue            5.00
1234             Ruler Red            5.00
1234             Ruler Blue           5.00
```

The formula I'm trying is below, to only populate if it's a ruler. But doesn't work.

```
=if(and(a2=1234,b2="Book*',b2="Pen*"),"0", C2))
```

Result expected:

```
Supplier_code    Item Description     Rate     Actual_Rate
1234             Pen Red              5.00     0
1234             Pen Blue             5.00     0
1234             Pen Black            5.00     0
1234             Book Black           5.00     0 
1234             Book Blue            5.00     0
1234             Ruler Red            5.00     5.00
1234             Ruler Blue           5.00     5.00
```

Comment: `b2="Book*' and b2="Pen*"`? Is there some portion of this vast multiverse where both these conditions can be true at the same time? If you're looking for rulers in that data set, I think you need `<>` (not equals).

Comment: In any case, if you're looking for something that *doesn't* contain ruler, it's a bad idea to use "pen or book", you should instead use "not ruler". The problem with your scheme becomes obvious when you start stocking staplers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your requirement is to populate only in case of Ruler, if thats the case use below formula

```
=if(and(a2=1234,b2="Ruler*"),"0", C2))
```